# Is it possible to make Bootstrap datepicker work with ui.mask?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, mask

I am trying to use Bootstrap datepicker with ui.mask, but I don't know how to make them work together. My format would be 'dd-MM-yyyy'
Is it possible?
With this code :

```
<input type="text" class="col-sm-5" ui-mask="99-99-9999" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dateDebut" is-open="opened1"  datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Fermer"/>
```

when I leave the input the date disappear, If I choose a date in the datepicker (22-05-2015) it writes 22/20/1500 in the input and I am getting this error :

> Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number
>   of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822
>   or ISO 8601 date.

Comment: Can you represent it on JsFiddle ?

Comment: here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/BwKxNb45AuRike0yzQCg?p=preview